# php regular expression parse data

Tags: php, regex

I have a field which contain 20 character (pad string with space character from right) like below:

> VINEYARD HAVEN MA
> BOLIVAR TN
> ,
> BOLIVAR, TN
> NORTH TONAWANDA, NY

How can I use regular expression to parse and get data, the result I want will look like this:

> [1] VINEYARD HAVEN [2] MA
>
> [1] BOLIVAR [2] TN
>
> [1] , or empty [2] , or empty
>
> [1] BOLIVAR, or BOLIVAR [2] TN or ,TN
>
> [1] NORTH TONAWANDA, or NORTH TONAWANDA [2] NY or ,NY

Currently I use this regex:

```
^(\D*)(?=[ ]\w{2}[ ]*)([ ]\w{2}[ ]*)
```

But it couldnot match the line:

> ,

Please help to adjust my regex so that I match all data above

Comment: it's not very clear what do you want to achieve :(

Answer (score 1):

What about this regex: `^(.*)[ ,](\w*)$` ? You can see working it here: http://regexr.com/3cno7.

---

Example usage:

```
<?php

$string = 'VINEYARD HAVEN MA
BOLIVAR TN
,
BOLIVAR, TN
NORTH TONAWANDA, NY';

$lines = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $string));

$pattern = '/^(.*)[ ,](\w*)$/';

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $res = preg_match($pattern, $line, $matched);

    print 'first: "' . $matched[1] . '", second: "' . $matched[2] . '"' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: just test your regex, it match the ",      " line but it didn't parse data for other lines :)

Comment: Here is example working code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f2d90bed6bdd2b8eacd47bbf03ba7b87acc6328 . How did you use it?

Comment: Site has some maintenance, I added that code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible to implement this in a regular expression (try `/(.*)\b([A-Z][A-Z])$/` ), however if you don't know how to write the regular expression you'll [never be able to debug it](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan). Yes, its worth finding out as a learning exercise, but since we're talking about PHP here (which does have a mechanism for storing compiled REs and isn't often used for bulk data operations) I would use something like the following if I needed to solve the problem quickly and in maintainable code:

```
$str=trim($str);
if (preg_match("/\b[A-Z][A-Z]$/i", $str, $match)) {
    $state=$match[0];
    $town=trim(substr($str,0,-2)), " ,\t\n\r\0\x0B");
}
```